# Perl error while installing XML::LibXSLT

Tags: perl

I am installing Perl module [`XML::LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXSLT), and I am getting the errors shown below.

```
Writing Makefile for XML::LibXSLT
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp LibXSLT.pm blib\lib\XML\LibXSLT.pm
E:\Perl\bin\perl.exe E:\Perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap E:\Perl\lib\ExtUtils\
typemap -typemap typemap  LibXSLT.xs > LibXSLT.xsc && E:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExt
Utils::Command -e mv -- LibXSLT.xsc LibXSLT.c
E:\Perl\site\bin\gcc.exe -c     -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DWIN64
-DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTE
XT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bit
fields -O2        -DVERSION=\"1.81\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"1.81\"  "-IE:\Perl\lib\CO
RE"  -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_EXSLT LibXSLT.c
LibXSLT.xs:12:32: fatal error: libxslt/xsltconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'LibXSLT.o'
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.81.tar.gz
  E:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Any idea to how to rectify this. Please let me know.

Actaully, I am installing this by using

> perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->force(qw(install XML::LibXSLT));

So, it is getting 'XML-LibXSLT-1.81.tar.gz' automatically and working this with Windows 7.

Comment: Is this ActivePerl? I would expect that ActivePerl has XML::LibXSLT available as ppm?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you said how you were trying to install the module. Is this `cpan` or `cpanm`, or are you doing it manually? It also looks like you're building on a Windows system, is that right?

The immediate problem is that the `gcc` compiler can't find `libxslt/xsltconfig.h`. It may be that the download wasn't unpacked correctly, but I see you are trying to build version **1.81** when the latest is **1.82**. You should really fetch the latest version before you try to build it.

Comment: I have some points on the above post for your question and pls let me know any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the headers files for libxslt. Did you install libxslt?

XML::LibXSLT's `README`:

> This module is a fast XSLT library, based on the GNOME libxslt engine
>   that you can find at http://www.xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
>
> ...
>
> ### A NOTE ON INSTALLATION
>
> The library depends on libxslt. You have to have both the library and
>   its header files installed (on various Linux/UNIX distributions thay
>   are usually packaged as libxslt-dev or libxslt-devel). The module can
>   further make use of libexslt, which is distributed with libxslt, but
>   on some systems packaged separately. These libraries may have their
>   own dependencies (usually resolved automatically by the packaging
>   system).
>
> ...